# Hourglass in fontawesome package

Tags: fontawesome

The following does not work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faHourglass
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
Use of \faHourglass doesn't match its definition \end
```

This is the *only* symbol in the [fontawesome](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome?lang=en) package that does not work for me. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try -- `\def\faHourglass{\faicon{hourglass}}` after `\usepackage{fontawesome}`  -- this looks like a bug in the package

Comment: It is a bug. The package also define `\faHourglass1` and this is simply wrong. A number of other symbols are faulty too e.g. \faBattery4.

Comment: Note that `\faHourglass3` will work because the package has overwritten its initial definition of `faHourglass` in a way which requires it to be followed by `3`. However, it may not give you the particular hourglass symbol you want.

Comment: https://github.com/xdanaux/fontawesome-latex/issues/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package does

```
\def\faHtml5{\faicon{html5}}

\def\faCss3{\faicon{css3}}

\def\faBattery3{\faicon{battery-3}}

\def\faBattery4{\faicon{battery-4}}

\def\faHourglass1{\faicon{hourglass-1}}

\def\faBattery0{\faicon{battery-0}}

\def\faBattery2{\faicon{battery-2}}

\def\faHourglass2{\faicon{hourglass-2}}

\def\faBattery1{\faicon{battery-1}}

\def\faHourglass3{\faicon{hourglass-3}}
```

While the first two give no real problem, provided you always use the literal input, the `\faHourglass` and `\faBattery` families will not work; only `\faBattery1` and `\faHourglass3` are legal.

I suggest fixing them like

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% fix the wrong symbols
\renewcommand{\faHourglass}[1][]{%
  \faicon{hourglass\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else-#1\fi}%
}
\renewcommand{\faBattery}[1][4]{%
  \faicon{battery-#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\faHourglass\ \faHourglass[1]\ \faHourglass[2]\ \faHourglass[3]

\faBattery\ \faBattery[0]\ \faBattery[1]\ \faBattery[2]\ \faBattery[3]\ \faBattery[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can simply fix `\faHourglass` and use the already existing synonyms.

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% fix the wrong symbol 
\renewcommand{\faHourglass}{\faicon{hourglass}}

\begin{document}

\faHourglass\ \faHourglassStart\ \faHourglassHalf\ \faHourglassEnd\ \faHourglassO

\faBatteryEmpty\ \faBatteryQuarter\ \faBatteryHalf\ \faBatteryThreeQuarters\ \faBatteryFull

\end{document}
```

[image]

Both tested with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`. Be sure to have the last version of `FontAwesome.otf`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround – redefine `\faHourglass`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\def\faHourglass{\ifxetex\FA\symbol{"F254}\else\FAone\symbol{169}\fi}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \faHourglassO & \faHourglass & %
  \faHourglassStart & \faHourglassEnd & \faHourglassHalf%\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get "Undefined control sequence \faHourglass" :/

Comment: Strange… Did you compile with `xelatex`?

Comment: Xelatex works, pdflatex does not.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I had forgotten the limit of 256 characters per font if one does not use the Opentype version.